# amount of Riemann scalar on a spherical shell in xAct

Tags: physics, tensors, xact

how can I Calculate the amount of Riemann scalar on a spherical shell?
(i used xCoba and I defined a manifold, then I defined a metric and a chart with theta and phi coordinates but I don't know how to continue my solution. should I use MetricCompute?)

```
DefManifold[M, 2, IndexRange[a, i]]
DefMetric[-1, metric[-a, -b], CD, {";", "\[Del]"}, PrintAs -> g];
DefChart[coordinate, M, {0, 1}, {\[Theta][], \[Phi][]}]
RiemannCD[-a, -b, -c, d]
```

this link is the mathematical description of the problem:
[enter link description here](http://einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/index.php/general-relativity/70-the-riemann-curvature-tensor-for-the-surface-of-a-sphere)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have tried.

Comment: thanks for your remark.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a mathematical description of what you're trying to do? I'm unclear on what you mean by "the Riemann scalar (Ricci scalar?) on a spherical  shell". Do you mean at some fixed value of the $r$ coordinate? Is there some kind of "thin shell" there modeled by some kind of stress-energy with a delta function in it?

Comment: thanks for your comment. sure, I edited my question and attached a link that includes a mathematical description. the question is about Riemann scalar, not Ricci. I think it refers to Gaussian curvatures